# Sass use variable value in @import

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

My code looks like this

```
      &.village {
        &.village- {
          @for $i from 1 through 12 {
            &#{$i} {
              background-image: url('../../images/maps/#{$i}.png');

              @import "maps/map-#{$i}";
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

But then I get this error:

> Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: 
>                         @import "maps/map-#{$i}";
>                        ^
>         File to import not found or unreadable: maps/map-#{$i}.

I use Laravel 5.6, I've tried looking it up but I didn't find anything so far. Is it possible to import a variable filename with scss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently [not possible](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/739), but some new features may be added to Sass in a near future.

You could achieve so by using conditionals to create the rules to match your imports. You could use `@if` for that (while we wait for a `@switch` statement to be [implemented](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/554)):

```
@mixin customImport($file) {
    @if $file == 'file-one' {
        @import 'file-one';
    } @else if $file == 'file-two' {
        @import 'file-two';
    }
}
```

Then later:

```
@include customImport('file-one');
```

Comment: I tried a mixin like this but got the following error: `Import directives may not be used within control directives or mixins`. Using SASS 3.5.6.

Comment: @JamesJones i think you just need to update your sass compiler version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 3.5.6 Is the latest Ruby SASS at time of writing. Is there something I'm missing?